# Heroku and R Build Error: "‘LC_MESSAGES’ undeclared"

Tags: r, heroku, rscript, cedar

I recently attempted to upgrade a `Heroku` app from `Cedar-14` to `Heroku-16`. I am using this: [Heroku buildpack for R](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r).

After the switch a bunch of R dependency install errors popped up, starting with

> error: ‘LC_MESSAGES’ undeclared (first use in this function)

**Output of sessionInfo():**

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
```

**Relevant output from heroku push:**

```
remote: -----> R Console app detected
remote:        NOTE: Using R version override [3.3.3]
remote: -----> Vendoring R 3.3.3 for heroku-16 stack (latest)
remote:        Retrieving R binaries from cache
remote: -----> Installing binary dependencies from Aptfile
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        Reading state information...
remote:        libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13).
remote:        libpq-dev is already the newest version (11.4-1.pgdg16.04+1).
remote:        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 152 not upgraded.

remote: -----> Executing R init script
remote:        Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
remote:        (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
remote:        also installing the dependency ‘rngWELL’
remote:
remote:        trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rngWELL_0.10-5.tar.gz'
remote:        Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61343 bytes (59 KB)
remote:        ==================================================
remote:        downloaded 59 KB
remote:
remote:        trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/randtoolbox_1.30.0.tar.gz'
remote:        Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1543760 bytes (1.5 MB)
remote:        ==================================================
remote:        downloaded 1.5 MB
remote:
remote:        * installing *source* package ‘rngWELL’ ...
remote:        ** package ‘rngWELL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
remote:        checking for gcc... gcc
remote:        checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
remote:        checking whether the C compiler works... yes
remote:        checking whether we are cross compiling... no
remote:        checking for suffix of executables...
remote:        checking for suffix of object files... o
remote:        checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
remote:        checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
remote:        checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
remote:        checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
remote:        checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
remote:        checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
remote:        checking for ANSI C header files... yes
remote:        checking for sys/types.h... yes
remote:        checking for sys/stat.h... yes
remote:        checking for stdlib.h... yes
remote:        checking for string.h... yes
remote:        checking for memory.h... yes
remote:        checking for strings.h... yes
remote:        checking for inttypes.h... yes
remote:        checking for stdint.h... yes
remote:        checking for unistd.h... yes
remote:        checking sys/time.h usability... yes
remote:        checking sys/time.h presence... yes
remote:        checking for sys/time.h... yes
remote:        checking time.h usability... yes
remote:        checking time.h presence... yes
remote:        checking for time.h... yes
remote:        checking windows.h usability... no
remote:        checking windows.h presence... no
remote:        checking for windows.h... no
remote:        checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
remote:        checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
remote:        checking for unsigned long long... yes
remote:        checking size of unsigned long long... 8
remote:        configure: creating ./config.status
remote:        config.status: creating src/config.h
remote:        config.status: src/config.h is unchanged
remote:        ** libs
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL1024a.c -o WELL1024a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL1024b.c -o WELL1024b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL19937a.c -o WELL19937a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL19937b.c -o WELL19937b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL19937c.c -o WELL19937c.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL21701a.c -o WELL21701a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL23209a.c -o WELL23209a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL23209b.c -o WELL23209b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL44497a.c -o WELL44497a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL44497b.c -o WELL44497b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL512a.c -o WELL512a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL521a.c -o WELL521a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL521b.c -o WELL521b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL607a.c -o WELL607a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL607b.c -o WELL607b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL800a.c -o WELL800a.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WELL800b.c -o WELL800b.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
remote:        gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rngWELL.c -o rngWELL.o
remote:        In file included from locale.h:58:0,
remote:                         from rngWELL.h:60,
remote:                         from rngWELL.c:55:
remote:        rngWELL.c: In function ‘doWELL’:
remote:        locale.h:59:19: error: ‘LC_MESSAGES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
remote:         #define _(String) dgettext ("rngWELL", String)
remote:                           ^
remote:        rngWELL.c:77:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘_’
remote:                 error(_("invalid argument"));
remote:                       ^

AND THEN A BUNCH OF SIMILAR ERRORS
```

After rolling back to Cedar-14, all was healthy again.

**Any ideas what might be going on here?**

Comment: This is a wild guess, but worth a try. I think something's trying to use the environment variable `LC_MESSAGES` but can't find it. I wonder if putting something like `Sys.setenv(LC_MESSAGES ="en_US.UTF-8")` at the start of `init.R` could help?

Answer (score 0):

the same issue was submitted in the [dev's github](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/issues/46). It seems to have been fixed in 2015. Please make sure the package is up to date. Also consider that, maybe, the maintainer have not released yet a version of Heroku which fits the newest version of R.

Best,

Elie